# Gradually refactoring pieces of a giant, monolithic VB6 winforms app to .Net

Tags: .net, vb6, vb6-migration

In a nutshell, the app looks up an instruction for something to do from a database, performs the action, and saves information about the success or failure of that action back to the database. It performs about 40 different actions, things like automating Office applications, copying files, running searches, etc.

The application is a single EXE, so everything runs in the main app's process space and that has been a major source of instability because it has to load a lot of 3rd party DLLs to do the work and they often will do something unsavory that crashes the entire app.

The plan: I want to move the code that does the dangerous heavy lifting out of the VB6 exe and into external processes that run independently of the main app. The original app will only handle the database stuff and initiate other processes to do it's bidding.

What is the best way to do this? If I was still in VB6 I think I would be building ActiveX EXEs to do this, but I'm not sure what the .Net equivalent is. Ideally the VB6 app would declare an object that instantiates the external process, and using methods of the object set parameters, execute the process, possibly receive progress notifications, and finally receive the results of the operation.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, spawning another process (via a console application or whatever) is probably not a good idea.  You have to worry about communicating with that process which can be a real hassle, and it's not really going to buy you any stability.  What I would probably do is use VB.NET to make a COM-Visible class library that uses [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) threads.

This will give you the ability to work in the background within the .NET library, and it won't really affect the VB6 application at all as long as you're careful about exception management (within the .NET library).  The VB6 application can wait for the .NET library to do the heavy lifting and feed it a nice friendly message.

Comment: Thanks Scott. The worst kind of error I'm trying to avoid is when code in a 3rd party dll causes a memory access violation and the host app just disappears, the error handler in VB6 never even fires. Does the solution you describe provide better protection against that sort of thing?

Comment: Likely not, sadly.  In this case, spawning another process is probably the only real way.  You could create a console application that writes to a log file on the hard drive.  You could then watch this file from VB6.  WCF could work, too.  You could write a .NET COM-Visible class library that calls a WCF service since you can't really call WCF directly from VB6.

Comment: I don't mean to say you can't call a WCF service from VB6 at all, it would just involve making the service RESTful and using VB6 to make some HTTP GET requests or something.

Comment: "You could write a .NET COM-Visible class library that calls a WCF service since you can't really call WCF directly from VB6" - its so obvious now! Thanks Scott, thats the direction I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, cannot say I have tried something like this before, but

**One possible solution**

1. Write an application\service that a) spawns child processes, and b) hosts a [WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548160/can-we-host-a-workflow-service-as-a-windows-service/2548349#2548349) to facilitate communication between processes
2. Write child processes to process "Actions"

**Another possible solution**

An alternative *may be* to use Windows Workflow Foundation 4. It is relatively stable and relatively easy to use (having dabbled in this myself). I do not know if it offers the **isolation** you require, but worth a look.

You would essentially authour your own custom activities to perform your actions, and then dynamically execute them via WorkflowInvoker.

**Yet another possible solution**

Yet another alternative that may be somewhat heavy handed but is somewhat more conventional in terms of single-process hosting and offers the isolation you require, would be to look into [Managed Add-in Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx) [MAF] (check out the link's section about isolation levels). It may be somewhat intimidating, but my friend [Kent Boogaart has done some nifty things with it](http://kentb.blogspot.com/search/label/MAF), and if you keep things simple it may just turn the trick.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. I was thinking WCF might play a role in this. How does one hook a VB6 app into WCF services?

Comment: hm, i am no vb expert but i am sure there are many examples [here on SO and elsewhere] to help you get started there. another two cents: i have always found it helpful to vet out and research methods and technologies that are *new to me* in simple mickey-mouse apps. once i understand how the new technology works *then* i begin to sort out how to apply it. give it a go :)

Comment: Thanks again, good advice - I will work it out in the sandbox first.

Comment: no worries, ack - just realised vb6 is not managed, did not realise there were interop issues too. hope this was somewhat helpful, and good luck! :)